# jqPlot donut chart with legends issue

Tags: jqplot

I have jqplot donut chart where I want to add chart labels in the center part. Also want to add scrolling for labels in the middle of graph. So only 1-2 labels in the center will be visible and rest will be visible when user scrolls.

Please have a look attached image. As per my knowledge, we can't add labels in the center of chart. Is there any way to do this? Appreciate your help.

My current code is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _chart5_plot_properties;
    _chart5_plot_properties = {
    title: " ",
    "seriesDefaults":{
          renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,              
          rendererOptions:{
            sliceMargin: 0,
            innerDiameter: 220,
            startAngle: -90,
            barPadding: 0,
            padding: 3,
          }
      },
      grid: {
        shadow: false,
        drawBorder: false,
        shadowColor: "transparent"
      },
      highlighter: {
        show: true,            
        tooltipLocation: "sw",          
        useAxesFormatters:false
      }
 }
 plot2 = $.jqplot("chart2", chart_data, _chart5_plot_properties);
```

[image: Example is attached]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an option for this in jqPlot.
Though, jqPlot has 8 options to position the legend, but it does not have the center option. [jqPlot Legend Locations](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Legend.location)

But after tweaking it a bit, I could accomplish it using jQuery. Since we need to require jQuery to render/draw jqPlot charts, so I thought of using jQuery rather than pure Javascript.

I have used two functions `defineDimensionsForLegendTable(parentContainerID, dimensions)` and `fixLegendsToCenter(parentContainerID)`

Other important things that you should not miss out while using these functions

- Make sure you include the `jquery.jqplot.js`, `jqplot.pieRenderer.js`, `jqplot.donutRenderer.js`, `jquery.jqplot.css` files (or the minified versions - .min.js)
- Set `placement` to `outsideGrid` in `legendOptions`

  `legend: { show:true, placement: 'outsideGrid' }`
- Give a higher z-index to the legend-table

  `#chart2 .jqplot-table-legend{
     z-index: 99999; 
  }`

Find the working fiddle here - [jqPlot Donut Chart with legend in the center](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/gfkc5fqp/3/)

Note: If the chart does not show up in Google Chrome, try opening it in Firefox or some other browser.

Remove the `console.log` lines from the code ;-)

You can use [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/http://foundation.zurb.com/) to beautify the scrollbar. :-)

Hope it helps :-)